# PhotoEditorSDK iOS can't edit added text

Tags: photoeditorsdk

My licenses includes **Text** feature, I can add text to the image; however, when I tap the text nothing happens, it should show a list of edit text options on the bottom. Please help me with that.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code samples of how you integrate the SDK

Comment: Hi @Sascha, check out the code:                                                                
    let photoEditViewController = PhotoEditViewController.init(photo: photo), 
    photoEditViewController.delegate = self, 
    present(photoEditViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Please report a bug at http://support.photoeditorsdk.com and make sure to include a code sample that reproduces the issue. Also please mention the link to this post in the bug report.